# How can I allow users to enter commas in a value that will be stored in an sql server 2005 numeric field?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes

I have a table field whose `Datatype` is `numeric(10, 1)`. This field stores the `AmountPaid` and the user prefers to enter the Amount Value with commas in between like `78,234,673` because that's what they're used to, otherwise they will making a lot of errors.

Is there a way I can allow commas in the value but remove them when saving, or is there a way I can go ahead and store them in `SQL-SERVER` without changing the `DATATYPE`?

Comment: How does the user enter the number? SQL Server does not care about commas and dots but the user interface application does. Anyway, the solution is for the user the select the desired reginal setting (including number format) on his computer. If the application he uses doesn't respect this it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text) is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how you're parsing the values from the UI, or what type you're parsing them as, but you may find that [`NumberStyles.AllowThousands`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) is what you're after. I assume you *are* parsing the user input as a number and passing that to SQL Server as a parameter value, rather than just including it in the SQL verbatim... if not, that's the first change to make.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure either what your after but if you want to basically pass into SQL an array of ints have you thought about passing in the string you have (which seems to be in Comma Seperated Values) and then splitting them into the values you need inside SQL. Then placing them in the desired table.

I had to do something similar a couple of days ago but it was to a Oracle database which doesn't have a split function so had to create one. The code is bellow, you should have no trouble translating it into SQL Server.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SPLIT_FNC IS
  -- Create a Type to be used as a temp table
  TYPE strArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(word IN VARCHAR2) RETURN strArray;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SPLIT_FNC IS
  FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(word IN VARCHAR2) RETURN strArray IS items strArray;
    temp NUMBER;
    delim CHAR := ',';
    start_index NUMBER := 1;
    end_index NUMBER := -1;
  BEGIN
    temp := 1;
    -- If INSTR can not find a match it will return 0
    WHILE end_index != 0 LOOP
      -- Find location of next comma
      end_index := INSTR(word, delim, start_index, 1);
      CASE 
        WHEN
          end_index = 0
        THEN
          -- Catch the last value
          items(temp) :=  SUBSTR(word, start_index);
        ELSE
          -- Get substring of start to next comma
          items(temp) :=  SUBSTR(word, start_index, end_index - start_index);
      END CASE;
      start_index := end_index + 1;
      temp := temp + 1;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN items;
  END SPLIT_STR;  
END SPLIT_FNC;
```

Hopefully this is helpful - Ankou